# Implementing a chart with AFreeChart into a View

Tags: android, view, charts, jfreechart

Here is my problem: I am using `AFreeChart` to display a chart in my activity. The reason why I used `AFreeChart` was because I first finished this chart with `JFreeChart`, and, realized after that, it wasn't compatible with Android.

So, with `AFreeChart`, I could create the same chart with exactly the same code, but I don't know how to display it on a `View`.

Here I am creating the chart:

```
private void creerGraphique(){

    //Here I have the creation of the DateSet

    AFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "Mois", // Title
                "Jours", // x-axis Label
                "Repetitions", // y-axis Label
                graph, // Dataset
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // Plot Orientation
                true, // Show Legend
                true, // Use tooltips
                false // Configure chart to generate URLs?
            );
}
```

Here I want to use it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graphique);

    this.stockTableau();
    this.creerGraphique();

            //HERE: How can I display it since it's already created
}
```

I downloaded the `AFreeChart` demo code, but a function which wasn't on the package was used, and so, I couldn't use it too.

I thank you for your help.

PS: I'm not an english, so I hope my problem is clear, do not hesitate to ask me more details.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the sample in AFreeChart? It's quite straight forward, look at what they did for this chart for instance :

http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/afreechart_sample/src/org/afree/chart/demo/view/PieChartDemo01View.java

They extend a DemoView which is basically an Android View with a setChart method, and pass the chart to the View.
So either extend DemoView or create you own equivalent if you don't need everything that's in it and follow the sample !

Good luck.

Comment: I thank you for this quick answer, this is the function I saw, which isn't in the package. I will try to create my own, and I hope it will work.

Comment: It worked! You have my thanks. I just have to modify it to meet my needs.

Comment: i need your help on this can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth noting that using the code you've pasted above, it would be helpful to call the chart's draw() method when you want it to draw.

As a simple example, if you were using a SurfaceView, you could create a method something like the following:

```
private void drawChart(AFreeChart chart, ChartRenderingInfo info) {
    getHolder.lockCanvas();
    chart.draw(canvas, area, info);
    getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Where 'canvas' and 'area' have been set.

This is useful if you are looking to do a very simple implementation where you don't want to use the DemoView discussed above.

Comment: Hello can i make a gantt chart using this library