# Creating a simple chart with AFreeChart for android

Tags: android

I am studying this example

https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/afreechart_sample/src/org/afree/chart/demo/view/PieChartDemo01View.java

but I do not understand how I can make an image with the library.

I intent to make a chart and generate an image but I not even able to create a chart.

I tried

`PieChartDemo01View p = new PieChartDemo01View(getApplicationContext());
PieChartDemo01View p = new PieChartDemo01View(new Activity());
PieChartDemo01View p = new PieChartDemo01View(this);`

All throws an exception.

Which activty should I have to pass to constructor to create the pie? And how can I put the pie in a ImageView? I wanna save the pie generated. The user could see the graphic later.

Comment: check [achartengine](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/achartengine/) it also help to create different chart.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply.
To create any Chart call this function which returns AFreeChart:

```
AFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(title, dataset, legend, tooltips, urls);
```

in which parameters are:

1. title for your pie chart.
2. PieDataset
3. Do you want legend or not ? (boolean)
4. tooltips (boolean)
5. urls (boolean)

Where `ChartFactory` is a AbstractClass and there you will get plenty of methods to create different type of charts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked this answear??Try to study the given sample...

[Implementing a chart with AFreeChart into a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200965/implementing-a-chart-with-afreechart-into-a-view)

---

Also you could use [achartengine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)(is different from yours).

1)Here is some [video](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2603F3CABBF5EEB0) tutorials see 0,1 and 5 videos to create a pie chart!

2) ***Another one [one pie chart tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-pie-chart-using-achartengine/).***

---

[And then if you want to  convert the graph (AChartEngine) into image see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484356/android-converting-graph-achartengine-into-image-using-tobitmap)

I don't know if this helps or if you want use only aFREEchartengine..
Hope it helps!

*try to put some more code of what you tried.No one can understands from these few lines what might be wrong..If you want to have good answears, give a more specific question..*